# Arc::new() is slow with cloned vectors

Tags: rust

After executing this:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Instant;
fn main() {
    let cap = 100000000;
    let b0 = vec![0; cap];
    let now = Instant::now();
    Arc::new(b0);
    println!("T0: {:?}", now.elapsed());
    let c0 = vec![0; cap];
    let _ = c0.clone(); // <- this makes it slow
    let now = Instant::now();
    Arc::new(c0);
    println!("T1: {:?}", now.elapsed());
}
```

The result is:
T0: 5.971µs
T1: 26.69574ms

Why the second Arc::new is slow if we clone c0 before?

**Edit:**

I tested it with:

- Windows 10, rust 1.44.1 debug
- Linux, rust 1.47-nightly release
- Linux, rust 1.18
- MacOS, rust 1.44.0-nightly release

T1's time increases linearly with the vector size.

Comment: I run with cargo run --release

Comment: This is actually a good question, reproducible in release mode (T0=9us, T1=1ms on my machine, compiled with `rustc -O`), and not deserving of downvotes. It's not quite clear if the reason is OS/machine or Rust related. `Arc::new` must move the content to its own new storage. Cloning requires the memory to be touched, which maybe disables some optimization possible in the first case.

Comment: This is most likely due to the way you measure the duration. `Arc::new()` should be fast for any vector, since it only allocates space for the the metadata of the vec (plus the reference counter) on the heap, and only this information will be moved. The actual vector data remains where it is. It looks like the compiler is reordering instructions here, so your second timing actually measures how long `Arc::new(c0.clone())` takes, which includes copying the whole vector.

Comment: I don't think this is the case:
I can measure the cloning operation separately (I wrap the problematic line with Instant::now() & now.elapsed()):
 
it takes 338.071658ms  and Arc::new is still slow

Comment: Godbolting the two versions confirms that the line `let _ = c0.clone()` is removed by the compiler as one would expect (because it's unobservable), and the two versions result in exactly the same assembly. This strongly suggests this is a measurement issue. A timing of `T1` of 26ms is really, really, really slow anyway, which suggests this is e.g. due to thread scheduling

Comment: @user2722968 they look pretty different : https://godbolt.org/z/79aGKE

Comment: The results are not dramatically different on playground btw: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=03dff53af0d1fa34b2c6b61fa312f42a ,  but not in my Windows PC it works slowly as OP suggest. It could be related with OS, not sure but playground probably operates on Linux

Comment: @Blezz use `drop(c0)` instead of a Box or Arc, it will still work slowly

Comment: @ÖmerErden I tried on Linux and Mac and I observe big slowdown.

Comment: @user2722968 see my previous comment, it is slow even if I am sure the c0.clone() was executed

Comment: Still, the compiler can reorder the code, and you don't know what you are timing here. My first guess (that the compiler is moving the clone operation) turned out to be wrong, but that just means the compiler is rearranging the code in some other way. I suggest trying to reproduce the result using `test::Bencher` or the `criterion` crate.

Comment: I'm getting about 5.4µs and 29µs respectively. Running it on the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=becab6dc72a1b1a583c25feb8a6c6720)  results in about 11µs and 12µs, while running it in debug in the playground doesn't print T1 at all

Comment: T0: 6.33µs, T1: 1.373273ms on aws c5n.xlarge(centos 7), T0: 32.616µs, T1: 37.717233ms on my Mac. T1 is slow

Comment: I think there is something with alloctor, when I use jemallocator (https://crates.io/crates/jemallocator), T0 8.162µs, T1 6.168µs

Comment: According to https://godbolt.org/z/jrYs9b the call to `clone` seems to be elided. At this point, I would recommend (1) editing the question with the version of rustc you use, the OS and architecture you compile for and (2) possibly posting the assembly code of the generated binary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that you are not measuring the time taken by the `Arc::new`, but instead you are measuring the time taken when the Arc is dropped (since you don't assign it to anything).

Note also that depending on your system, this line:

```
let b0 = vec![0; cap];
```

may not allocate any physical memory: it can allocate only virtual space, with the physical memory being allocated and zeroed on the first time it is accessed. This is confirmed by cachegrind that shows almost no cache misses until the buffer is cloned.

Cloning the vector has two side effects:

- It causes the physical memory to be mapped, which means that it must be unmapped when dropping the `Arc`,
- It trashes the cache (due to the memory zeroing and copying), which causes cache misses in the subsequent code.

Using the following code, which moves the deallocation out of the measured timings, the times are much faster and closer:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
   let cap = 1000000000;
   let b0 = vec![0; cap];
   let now = Instant::now();
   let a = Arc::new(b0);
   println!("T0: {:?}", now.elapsed());
   drop (a);
   let c0 = vec![0; cap];
   let _ = c0.clone(); // <- this makes it slow
   let now2 = Instant::now();
   let a = Arc::new(c0);
   println!("T1: {:?}", now2.elapsed());
   drop (a);
}
```

The second `Arc::new` is still slower, but the difference can be explained by the 3 extra L3-cache misses reported by cachegrind.

Comment: Nice catch with the `drop` observation! Do you know why cloning the `Arc` causes the memory to be mapped? I would not have thought that cloning the `Arc` would have any effect on the memory map because it has no reason to dereference the pointer.

Comment: @trentcl It's not the `Arc` that's cloned, it's the vector before the `Arc` is created.

Comment: Ohhh. *facepalm* Guess it's time for another cup of caffeinated fluid.